# Add event handler to get Button Click on a LeadPage where I can just code on the body

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, buttonclick

I am trying to add a virtual pageview to be used in GA in a leadpage to track a button click.

I would like to add the following code to the button

```
<a href=”/Test/example” onclick=”javascript:pageTracker._trackPageview (‘example’);”target=”blank”>
```

but the problem is the fact that I have not full access to the page and therefore I cannot access directly the button(s).

Since I can add code to the "Body" section, I would like to add the event handler to this section to get the click event.
Any suggestion about how can I do it ? Which code should I use?

Comment: What is with the fancy quotes? And the `javascript` is useless in an onclick tag.

Answer (score 0):

So you can add onclick to the elements. Basic idea

```
$(function() {  //ready
    $("a").on("click", function() {  //add click events to the anchors
        pageTracker._trackPageview(this.href);  //log what you want
    });
});
```